# GET Method Is Not Calling In IE

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, get

I am new to AngularJs & Spring. I am calling Spring MVC GET Method from AngularJs function. Sometime GET method is not called up and giving old session values. If i use POST its working fine.

Please comment if need more details about it.

### Spring MVC method :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getAccessDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody ProcessDO getAccessDetFromSession(HttpServletRequest request){
    AccessDO accessDO = null;
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();
    if(session.getAttribute("accessDetail")!=null) {
        accessDO =(AccessDO) session.getAttribute("accessDetail");
    }
    return accessDO ;
}
```

### AngularJS Function :

```
$scope.loadDetails = function(){
    $http.get(CONTEXT+'/getAccessDetails').then(function(resp){
        alert(resp.data); // Getting old value
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ?. Your method signature is of type `ProcessDO` and it must return a value of type `ProcessDO`.

Comment: Sudhir, Am not getting any error..yes it will return ProcessDO..

Answer (score 1):

[Targets of caching operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching#Targets_of_caching_operations)

I think this explains your issue.
This is happening because your response is getting cached and when you are trying again you are getting cached response in case of GET.

While post method doesn't get cached neither it get saved in browser history.

you can also refer[http_methods_get_post_difference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) this link

Comment: Thank Gaurav, let me look into it.